# how to come my site first in google search?

Tags: seo

i have a site http://fb2magic.com. when i search 'fb2magic' in google, my site is at 5th page. how to move it to first.
i am added 'fb2magic' in title, meta discription, meta keyword etc.

```
 <title>see the magic of fb | Fb2magic</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="fb2magic, footballer in you, football, facebook2magic, facebook to magic, magic facebook application, facebook application,Facebook Magic App World " />
<meta name="description" content="fb2magic is a group of magic applications. Here you can see the magic of facebook. Use our facebook magic applications. its very interesting.">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fb2magic is your brand anchor text.
Use the word in the following sections to get that ranked into top 1 very easily:

- Use the word f2bmagic as anchor text in the home page
- Should be presented in the homepage at least thrice
- Place it in the first word of Meta title.
- Include the word in the H1 tag, partial relevant tag in the H2, 35% relevant tag in the H3.
- Social signals
- Local business listings in the name Fb2magic
- Few forum accounts and blogs. (Keep the back link anchor Fb2magic)

Answer (score -1):

You need t optimize your homepage better.

1. Title Tag should not be longer than 164 characters in length
2. Meta Description Tag should not be shorter than 125 characters in length
3. Google doesn't give any value to Meta Keywords
4. Have more on-page content on your homepage (as of now you have very less content on homepage).
5. BackLink your homepage from you social (facebook|twitter) profile pages